# Getting 200 ok status but giving response error from postman

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

Getting response 200 ok status but giving response error from postman
bosy

```
 {
        "errors": "Unable to log you in, please try again.",
        "success": false
    }
```

Post Url: https://demo.cognitonetworks.com/cognito/gettoken

[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]

```
@csrf_exempt
    def token_new(request):      
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('username')
        print email
        try:
            UserObj = CognitoUser.objects.get(user__email=email)
            username =  UserObj.user.username
            group = UserObj.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Admin','Manager'])
            group_name = ''
            if group:
                group_name = group[0].name                                                     
        except:
            return JsonResponseUnauthorized("Unable to log you in, please try again.")                    
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                TOKEN_CHECK_ACTIVE_USER = getattr(settings, "TOKEN_CHECK_ACTIVE_USER", False)
                if TOKEN_CHECK_ACTIVE_USER and not user.is_active:
                    return JsonResponseForbidden("User account is disabled.")
                token = token_generator.make_token(user)
                data = {
                    'token': token,
                    'user': user.pk,
                    'userName':UserObj.user.username,
                    'companyId':UserObj.company.companyid,
                    'companyApikey':UserObj.company.apikey,
                    'group_name':group_name
                }
                request.session['token'] = token
                request.session['token'] = user.pk
                return JsonResponse(data)
            else:
                return JsonResponseUnauthorized("Unable to log you in, please try again.")
        else:
            return JsonError("Must include 'username' and 'password' as POST parameters.")
    else:
        return JsonError("Must access via a POST request.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple, the server just accept your request and return you a `json`:

```
{ "errors": "Unable to log you in, please try again.", "success": false }
```

the problem is not on the client or server, you should just read:

> Unable to log you in, please try again

Comment: what might be the problem

Comment: Bad authentication

Comment: but i am able to login with that given username and password... same authentication i am passing here?